# How to get a particular key value pair from elm object

Tags: elm

I have a elm object which returns value are as follows

```
type alias Info =
    { name : String
    , stdId : stdKey
    , pemId : PermanentKey
    }
```

This info lies in a page named as class.elm

in another page i want to use the std key alone to do a if else comparison.
i tied to assign the stdKey to a variable like as follows

```
     uniKey = class.Info.stdId
```

But the elm doesn't accept this way .
Kindly help.

Comment: The `type alias Info` declaration does *not* create a variable, it defines a custom type.

`stdKey` should be a type, hence should be `StdKey`, a type for which you must provide a type definition. Ex. `type alias StdKey = String`

Comment: I wonder what was the error message Elm gave you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you intend to create a Info value in the Class.elm file and use it in an Other.elm file :

file Class.elm

```
module Class exposing (Info) 

type alias Info =
    { name : String
    , stdId : StdKey
    , pemId : PermanentKey
    }

type alias StdKey = String
type alias PermanentKey = String

info : Info
info = 
   { name = "name"
   , stdKey = "valueForStdKey"
   , pemKey = "valueForPemKey"
   }
```

file  Other.elm

```
module Other exposing (..)

import Class

uniKey : Class.StdKey
uniKey = Class.info.stdKey
```

Alternative
file  Alt.elm

```
module Alt exposing (..)

import Class exposing (StdKey, PermanentKey, info)

uniKey : StdKey
uniKey = info.stdKey
```

Comment: the 
type alias StdKey = String
type alias PermanentKey = String
both are from different page , can i import it same as you have told.

Comment: Yes. All values and types can be shared through importing the modules where they are defined.  And if you use `exposing` you won't have to prepend the value or the type with the name of the imported module.

Answer (score 2):

Elm automatically generates a `.stdId` function that works on any record with that field

```
.stdId info == info.stdId
```